# Does SOG Elite M20 mouse run on Linux?

Tags: linux, windows, mouse, compatibility

I'm about to install Linux on my laptop instead of Windows so i'm looking for the softwares and hardware that are compatible with Linux .

I have a Spirit Of Gamer Elite M20 mouse that I have been using for about a year, but when I checked the box that comes with that mouse and the official website of SOG, I didn't find any instruction indicating that it's compatible with linux versions, yet it was indicated that's compatible with most versions of Windows.

So does this mean that my mouse won't run on Linux ? (note that it comes with a software to customize colors, DPI and polling rate)
And if the mouse itself runs, will its software run too?

Please help me , I'm still beginner in Linux and I don't know much information about it, I got used to Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will 'work' for a simple definition of 'work'. It will point & it will click.

All the rest will be dependant on the specialist drivers/control panel… which certainly seem to be Windows only, as you suspect.

[Google Translate - English version of their homepage](https://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=fr&tl=en&u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.spiritofgamer.com%2Felite-m20_gamingmouse%2F&prev=search&sandbox=1)

Comment: If they don't make the control panel for anything other than Windows, you will not be able to use all the 'features' on anything other than Windows. Blame the manufacturer for thinking there's no other operating system:/

Answer (score 1):

The
[Spirit Of Gamer Elite M20](http://www.spiritofgamer.com/centre-de-telechargement/)
is only furnished with software for Windows.

I assume it will work on Linux as any other mouse, using basic functions.

Comment: That website is pretty opaque, isn't it;) Determinedly in French only & direct click to download, without warning. Badly thought out.